# String Arg is read incorrectly in c

Tags: linux, string

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *strInput = argv[1];
  printf("%s\n", strInput);
}
```

`./a.out $6$AS$9IwGTn5WbHSalUs4ba3JbOfOUX/v1yD71Z4M2F6Yusz5k2WQEOFxqLIY80tudGtcFttqr/Zq6RIPjHkl/t2Pp1`

When running the following program the characters `$6$AS$9` are cut from the input using args. Why is this?

Comment: Your shell is treating things that start with a `$` as shell variables, which are undefined and so expand to nothing. After `$9` it treats the rest as text. Try echoing your long string with `echo` and see what it prints.

Comment: Alternatively, escape the `$` symbols, e.g. `\$6\$A\$9....`

Comment: You should tag questions like this with Linux, because the answer doesn't really have anything to do with C programming.

Comment: Would "quoting" the argument prevent its expansion?

Comment: @WeatherVane On bash, single quotes would do it. Double quotes wouldn't. But I guess we don't know what OS and shell they are using.

Comment: I was running this on ubuntu a pair of single quotes around the input solved this problem. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Problem

This isn't anything to do with your program and how it treats arguments.

Your shell is treating things that start with a `$` as shell variables, which are undefined and so expand to nothing. After `$9` it treats the rest as text.

##### Solution

Enclose the argument in single quotes to prevent the shell from expanding variables: `'$6$A$9....'`